# How to return JSON object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, looker

I am having issues with returning a JSON object. When I render the webpage, nothing shows up. Does anyone know how to fix this? Sorry, I am new to Javascrtipt.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from 'react'

export const MarketData = () => {
  var obj = {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    symbolsGroups: [
      {
        name: 'Indices',
        originalName: 'Indices',
        symbols: [
          {
            name: 'INDEX:DEU30',
            displayName: 'DAX Index',
          },
          {
            name: 'FOREXCOM:UKXGBP',
            displayName: 'FTSE 100',
          },
        ],
      },
      ...
    ],
    showSymbolLogo: true,
    colorTheme: 'dark',
    isTransparent: false,
    locale: 'en',
    largeChartUrl:
      'https://bondintelligence.cloud.looker.com/extensions/bond_intelligence_webpage::helloworld-js/',
  }

  return (
    <>
      <text>{obj}</text>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `JSON.stringify()`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

The third argument in `JSON.stringify()` provides new lines and indentation. If only the first argument is provided, the string will be one long line.

Your example with fix (I changed your `<text>` to `<p>` as I have never heard of a `<text>` HTML element):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from 'react'

export const MarketData = () => {
  var obj = {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    symbolsGroups: [
      {
        name: 'Indices',
        originalName: 'Indices',
        symbols: [
          {
            name: 'INDEX:DEU30',
            displayName: 'DAX Index',
          },
          {
            name: 'FOREXCOM:UKXGBP',
            displayName: 'FTSE 100',
          },
        ],
      },
      ...
    ],
    showSymbolLogo: true,
    colorTheme: 'dark',
    isTransparent: false,
    locale: 'en',
    largeChartUrl:
      'https://bondintelligence.cloud.looker.com/extensions/bond_intelligence_webpage::helloworld-js/',
  }

  var objAsString = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)

  return (
    <>
      <p>{objAsString}</p>
    </>
  )
}
```